# ADALiOS seems to be redirecting my login to login.live.com

Tags: ios, adal

I'm trying to use ADALiOS framework v1.2.4 to acquire a token with a specific resource and clientId. I'm using a custom authority hosted on 'microsoftonline.com'.

I create an authentication context from within a VC thusly:

```
ADAuthenticationError *error = nil;
ADAuthenticationContext context = [[ADAuthenticationContext alloc] initWithAuthority:@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/somethingcustom/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=some_signin_policy"
    validateAuthority:YES
    tokenCacheStore:nil
    error:&error];
context.parentController = self;
```

And then I proceed to acquire a token thusly:

```
[context acquireTokenWithResource:@"someResource"
    clientId:@"someClientId"
    redirectUri:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someAppScheme://moreStuff"]
    completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {

        NSLog(@"Was here!");

}];
```

What I would expect to happen is that a UIWebView would open and redirect me to my custom authority sign-in page where I can enter my credentials. To confirm, that's what I see when I type in my custom authority URL into any old browser.

However, instead what I see happening is that the code redirects me to `login.live.com` that (A) looks different and (B) doesn't recognize my login credentials.

When I turn verbose logging on, I see the following line in the logs:

`VERBOSE: HTTP Protocol. Additional Information: HTTPProtocol::connection:willSendRequest:. Redirect response: https://login.microsoftonline.com/somethingcustom/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=someClientID&resource=someResourceID&redirect_uri=something%3A%2F%2Fsomethingelse&state=bunchOfStuff&x-client-CPU=64&x-client-DM=iPhone&x-client-Ver=1.2.4&x-client-SKU=iOS&x-client-OS=9.2.1&client-request-id=70E51F25-FD3D-4F98-8EDF-04CD19320A98. New request:https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%3drQIIAWVQTWsTUQD0ZVfQXFo8iKUHPUQQ4W33vX2bbAqCxdhtpEnoJhF3b-9ru5u-l63Z3TTJj_BQL6U_wWNPpf9ByFG8CIIg_gIvgokHETzMMMwMc5jqbWRhizw1kIV2a9gWji0wgq5w65Aw2oBNwWLYWAVe3LQxJfXJverm44ffTp_9uui9-2J-3MLVi2sAlgB8B-C8cn_Yfnm0ZzvIUwI9P9Y0VRbP9LICPlc2entlkeA1ZZN0Ib_-55wbGxldO9aaeSbkpfEehAOUiYPgjM-Hi6P-cB6kK-jZNMKqPNToNHReTTluauE3S-arMuq7I4Zt3TmJ8uhNgrgTFEzvz8K-O2X_9l_86Wk-QjpqJarrd87Cvk26g_bscBCchIuw6LX2VWeOkq7fJr1WMIr81yoctT8YtVh4knCbQs9dPUYEr0MPSQdSwjyPcCElw1fGtpKzMi_0mL6lVjbWKZ9kERYX61NujFodIe46jEFkYxsSKuRqJKaQNmKXUSFiD6FPBlia4IdZvQM2Kw_MR7eegJ8muLm7lWdaFkk6Pt7d2fmrpcrlbw2&id=. ErrorCode: 0.`

I'm guessing I'm doing something very wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building iOS apps with Azure AD B2C, I'd recommend starting with this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-ios/.  The version of ADAL you are using doesn't support B2C.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For automatically redirecting to custom authority sign-in page instead of common Microsoft landing page, I use `extraQueryParameters` while getting the token as:

```
[context acquireTokenWithResource:@"someResource"
clientId:@"someClientId"
redirectUri:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someAppScheme://moreStuff"]
extraQueryParameters:@"domain_hint=AzureADDomain.co.uk"
    completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {

    NSLog(@"Was here!");

}];
```

Hope this helps someone.